# Limit items in collection with HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

In my model I have two entities: Person and Puppy (to simplify it :) ). There is One To Many relationship between them so each Person has collection of puppies.

Now want to write HQL query which will list all persons with name "John" but also limit puppies to those older than 2 months.

my first try looked like this:

```
SELECT p FROM Person p
JOIN FETCH p.puppies pu
WHERE p.name = 'John'
AND pu.age > 2
```

But it doesn't work because this query selects ONLY those persons who have AT LEAST one puppy older than two months but not those who have only younger. And I also want to see them just with empty puppy list.

Effectively I would like to achieve something like (pseudo code):

```
SELECT p FROM Person p
JOIN FETCH p.puppies pu HAVING (pu.age > 2 )
WHERE p.name = 'John'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve my problem using  [hibernate filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-filters)

First I had to define my filter:

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name="olderThan", parameters=@ParamDef( name="months", type="integer" ) )
public class Person{
  @OneToMany
  @Filter(name="olderThan", condition="age > :months")
  private List<Puppy> puppies;
}
```

And then before executing the query filter has to be enabled:

```
public class PersonRepository{
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  public List<Person> findPeopleWithPoppiesLimitedToOlderThan(int months){
    em.unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter("olderThan").setParameter("months", months);
    return em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person LEFT JOIN FETCH p.puppies WHERE p.name = 'John'", Person.class).getResultList();
  }
}
```

and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

[HQL supports various kinds of joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins). So, you may use a left (outer) join like so:

```
FROM Person p
LEFT OUTER JOIN p.puppies pu
WHERE p.name = 'John'
AND pu.age > 2
```

This should give you all Johns without puppies, too. You say "...but not those who have only younger". Don't quite understand that. Why would you want to see those with younger puppies if explicitly declare `AND pu.age > 2`?

Comment: This Is not what I want. And btw my query looks like that (just without OUTER which is optional if you use LEFT). Maybe I didn't explain prosaically enough what my problem is. I want ALL persons with name JOHN, but limit their poppies to the once older then 2 months.  So if there is some JOHN with 2 puppies: 1 month and 3 months, I should get It with one puppy only. And if there is second JOHN with one puppy which is 1 month then still I should get this person just with empty puppy list.  (look at my pseudo-code query. I think it shows the idea)